# Keep set number of backup files

Tags: arrays, powershell, rotation, backup, delete-file

I have some files & folders I want to back up using powershell.  I'm using arrays to hold the file extensions I want to back up into one backup, and then I'm backing up the entire folder as well.  The zip files I create are named TxtFileBkup_yyyymmdd_hhMMss.zip and FldrBkup_yyyymmdd_hhMMss.zip.

I build the list of items to back up (by extension) as follows:

```
$extArray = @("*.txt","*.asc")
foreach ($ea in $extArray) {
    $filelist += Get-ChildItem $ToBeZipped"\*" -Recurse -Include $ea |Select-Object fullname
}

foreach ($fn in $fileList) {
    $fileName = $fn.FullName
    create-7zip $filename $zipFolder\$DataFileOut
    }
```

The folder is then backed up separately in an additional step.

Later on, I set the attribute byte of all files in the backup folder, then count the number of files in the folder matching a certain pattern, and if it's over 5, I un-set the attribute byte that is checked (and deleted) in the next run.

```
$delfiles=0 
$delfiles= (dir $zipFolder\TargetBackup*.zip).count-5 
if ($delfiles -gt 0) 

# If there are more than 5 zipped backups, we'll turn off the archive bit on them
{dir $zipFolder\TargetBackup* | sort-object -property {$_.CreationTime} |
select-object -first $delfiles |
foreach-object { attrib $_.FULLNAME -A} }}
```

What I would like to do is to store the generic backup names (TxtFileBkup, FldrBkup) in an array along with a number of backups I would want of them, and then use that array & nbr of backups to determine and mark backups to be deleted the next time the script runs. A bonus would be if I could use that array with or without the array of file extensions & the folder backup (so it would be 1 step to create both sets of backups).

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a hash table of the file prefixes and retention counts, and export that to xml

```
$bkup_counts = @{
TxtFileBkup = @('File',5)
FldrBkup = @('Folder',6)
}

$bkup_counts | export-clixml bkup_counts.xml
```

In your delete script, import that:

```
$bkup_counts = import-clixml bkup_counts.xml
```

and foreach through the hash table keys to do the gci, and you've got the desired retention count for that type as value of the table entry with that key.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Using your suggestion, I have it kinda working, except for one other thing.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Using your suggestion, I have it kinda working, except for one other thing.  I have two types of backups I am going to have - File and Folder, which would coincidentally be the type of backups I'm creating in the XML (txtfilebkup would be where I'm backing up text files & would use one name, the other would be where I am backing up folders & would use the other name.  I can make it grab the first & last of that xml file, but then backups would only work for 2 entries.  I'd like to have it where I could back up txt in one, asc in another, xml in another, and folders.

Comment: Edited. Hash table values can also be arrays, so you can store multiple values in each one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have after utilizing your sample code. (Thanks, BTW).

```
$bkup_Counts = @{
FldrBkup = 5
txtBkup = 6
}

$type = $null
#set Backup Types from the array we just defined
foreach ($type in $bkup_Counts.Keys) {
    $bkupTypeArr += $type
    }
# nameConv has dt stamp of getdate, 
# fArray will have filename in it FldrBkupYYYYMMDD_HHmmSS.zip and
#     txtBkupYYYYMMDD_HHmmSS.zip
$type = $null
foreach ($type in $bkup_Counts.Keys) {
    $fArray += $type + $nameConv
    }
# Array of extensions txt, asc 
foreach ($ea in $extArray) {
    $filelist += Get-ChildItem $ToBeZipped"\*" -Recurse -Include $ea |Select-Object fullname
}
```

What I need to do though, is to have a way to associate a set of extensions, with a set of bkup types, and then associate those backup types with a file or folder set of backups.

example -
f1.txt
f2.txt
f3.asc
f4.asc
  all would zip into txtBkup....zip
x1.xml
x2.xml
  all would zip into xmlBkup....zip
folder
  c:\myfiles would zip into fldrBkup....zip

I need to be able to associate a set of file extensions with a backup type and to loop thru those backing up files, then go forward with the folder backups.

Comment: You can accept your own answer, so that this question is recorded as completed....